# What does Time.time actually do?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Well I have a code

```
void redBowlValley(){
    if (timeStampR2 <= Time.time && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.DownArrow) && canFire == true) {
        Vector3 whereToSpawnR= GameObject.Find ("PlayerRedBowl").transform.position;
        Vector3 whereToSpawnR2= GameObject.Find ("PlayerRedBowl2").transform.position;
        Vector3 whereToSpawnR3= GameObject.Find ("PlayerRedBowl3").transform.position;
        Vector3 whereToSpawnR4= GameObject.Find ("PlayerRedBowl4").transform.position;
        Vector3 whereToSpawnR5= GameObject.Find ("PlayerRedBowl5").transform.position;
        Instantiate (PRedBowl, whereToSpawnR, Quaternion.identity);
        Instantiate (PRedBowl, whereToSpawnR2, Quaternion.identity);
        Instantiate (PRedBowl, whereToSpawnR3, Quaternion.identity);
        Instantiate (PRedBowl, whereToSpawnR4, Quaternion.identity);
        Instantiate (PRedBowl, whereToSpawnR5, Quaternion.identity);
        timeStampR2 = Time.time + CDRR2;
    }

}
```

This code applies a cooldown for redBowlValley. But I don't understand one thing. It says if timeStampR <= Time.time. And this is true after a few seconds. What actually decreases the time? How timeStampR2 is getting equal to Time.time? What is even Time.time?

> Edit: or time.Time is just getting increased and is that how it is get
>   equalled to timeStampR2?

Comment: A single search (for `Time.time unity`) provided [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html): "The time at the beginning of this frame . This is the time in seconds since the start of the game."

Answer (score 2):

`Time.time` is the time at the beginning of this frame (Read Only). This is the time in seconds since the start of the game. It returns the same value if called multiple times in a single frame. Each frame the value of `Time.time` is increased as the seconds passed since the game started increases.

In your example a function is called if `timeStampR2 <= Time.time` (and if other variables are `true`). Here you are waiting till the value of `timeStampR2` in seconds has passed.

If `timeStampR2 = 5`, for example, as the game ran each frame, the value of `Time.time` would increase from `0`. When `Time.time = 5` (`5` seconds have passed since you clicked play) then `timeStampR2 <= Time.time`would be `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Time.time returns the time since the game started, according to unity.